# jQuery Ajax form only sends last of several checkbox values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to submit a form with jQuery's $.ajax() function and it works, aside from the fact that it only sends the value of the last of several checkboxes, regardless of how many I check. I'd appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

The HTML form:

```
<form name="contactFormSmall" id="contactFormSmall" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="textfieldname" value="textfieldvalue" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Testvalue One" checked="checked" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Testvalue Two" checked="checked" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Testvalue Three" checked="checked" />
</form>
```

Here's the jQuery handling the form:

```
var fields = $(":input").serializeArray();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15",
    url: "includes/contact_process_small.php",
    data: fields,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#contactFormSmall').hide();
        $("#formFeedback").html(data).show();
    }

});
```

And here's the result from print_r($_POST) in the php script:

```
Array
(
    [textfieldname] => textfieldvalue
    [checkboxes] => Testvalue Three
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`name="checkboxes"` is correct only on a single element, you have to use `name="checkboxes[]"`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew you had to do that with PHP but I guess I figured jQuery would take care of it somehow.

Comment: It's just how HTML works: each name is sent in the POST request as a variable, and if more than one input element has the same it just gets overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

better way serialize form
like this
data: $('#contactFormSmall').serialize(),
and change to name="checkboxes[]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('form#contactFormSmall').serializeArray();
```

Comment: @Skumberg you need to change the name of checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute is the key in the key value pair of the POST data. So use either name="checkboxes[]" to create an array or use:

```
<form name="contactFormSmall" id="contactFormSmall" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="textfieldname" value="textfieldvalue" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxA" value="Testvalue One" checked="checked" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxB" value="Testvalue Two" checked="checked" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxC" value="Testvalue Three" checked="checked" />
</form>
```

to obtain the value of each checkbox individually (which is more likely to be what you want).